# Laptop , Tearing , white dots on screen. Only when adapter is on

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia

I have the following laptop , bought last September.

```
Operating System
    Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
CPU
    AMD Ryzen 7 4800H 46 °C
    Renoir 7nm Technology
RAM
    16,0GB Single-Channel DDR4 @ 1197MHz (16-16-16-39)
Motherboard
    TongFang GK7NP5R (FP6)
Graphics
    Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080@60Hz)
    4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650  42 °C
    ATI AMD Radeon Graphics (4800H)
    ForceWare version: 472.12
    SLI Disabled
    CrossFire Disabled
Storage
    465GB Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB (Unknown (SSD))
    465GB Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB (Unknown (SSD))
Optical Drives
    No optical disk drives detected
Audio
    Realtek High Definition Audio
```

Yesterday , I suddenly noticed tearing and white dots while playing a video file, it was late and closed the laptop.
Today I noticed sudden tearing and white dots, even when just browsing with chrome.

- I installed the latest drivers for AMD Radeon and the latest for Nvidia.
- I uninstalled the drivers and installed an older driver for both of them.
- Reduced the refresh rate from 120mhz to 60.

Now the weird part is that it does this ONLY ,when I put my adapter on , not when it is running on battery alone.

Anyone has any tips , but mostly, is this a software problem , or might their be something wrong with the hardware.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

By adapter, I assume you mean *power supply* or *charger*. Try another charger; the one causing the issue likely has a filter capacitor gone bad, allowing high-frequency AC leakage (AKA *ripple*) into the laptop.

- If the test charger works without issue:

  - If the radio-frequency interference (RFI) is mild, you could try adding [ferrite beads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) on the input and output cables.
  - If there's a bit more RFI, you could try putting a ceramic capacitor in the DC output line, if you have expertise with electronic repairs.
  - If there is significant ripple on the DC charging line, get a new power supply.
- If the test power supply shows the same issue, then RFI is coming from a switching power supply *in the laptop itself*, which likely will require professional repair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I will try to test it out with a different charger.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily it was a Nvidia driver issue.

I removed, with [Display Driver Uninstaller Download version 18.0.5.1](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html),  all the GPU drivers I had (Radeon AMD + Nvidia).

Reinstalled them to the latest again... and it did resolve the issue.